# C# project unable to find GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for google vision

Tags: c#, monodevelop, google-vision

I am trying to use googles vision api with my c# project. I am using the test code they provide but for some reason my code can't find the google_application_credentials here is the error:

*The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.*

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
namespace Test
{
    public class Vision
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Instantiates a client
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            // Load the image file into memory
            var image = Image.FromFile("wakeupcat.jpg");
            // Performs label detection on the image file
            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Documentation(https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries)
tells me to export the enviornment variable *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* which is what I do. But I still get the error above. please help!

Answer (score 1):

Download the JSON file from service account in google cloud vision and put in your Local system and then check it. This will work.

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
namespace Test
{
    public class Vision
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // set this environment
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\....\.json");
            // Instantiates a client
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            // Load the image file into memory
            var image = Image.FromFile("wakeupcat.jpg");
            // Performs label detection on the image file
            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```